# 403 error when enabling force ssl on godaddy

Tags: php, apache, ssl

I have a website on godaddy and every thing working fine until I bought a ssl certificate and install it on my website.

my problem is when I enable force ssl I get 403 error, and to get my website opened I have to add www or https manually.

without force ssl every thing working fine.

this is some information about my website:

- apache server
- php (laravel framework 5.2)
- godaddy hosting

With much thanks.

Comment: You should ask this question to them. They will help you. You are paying their services, right? :)

Comment: yes, Thank you. I will contact them to solve me the problem